# Why isn't dealloc being called in the represented object of my collection view item?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got a straightforward NSCollectionView that's configured straight out of Apple's guide. A few data points:

- My app empties its collection view whenever a new task is started and then fills it back up with items.
- I noticed that repeatedly running the same task causes the memory usage to grow and Instruments is telling me that the new memory is mostly the NSViews in the collection view.
- If I copy the item as it's being added to my array controller's content array then dealloc gets called on the instance that is copied (as expected).
- I'm using ARC

I've [modified Apple's IconCollection sample code](http://cl.ly/TGx4) slightly to illustrate the issue:

- added a 5 second timer that flushes the collection view and rebuilds its contents.
- added a simple NSImage subclass for the icon with dealloc implemented to log its invocation.

If you profile the app in instruments and set a mark after each refresh you'll see the problem.

What the heck is going on here?

**Update**

My original sample project was not a good example of the problem. I've since recreated a sample file from scratch and I've discovered the cause for my problem but I don't completely understand why my mistake is causing the content objects to be held onto.

The gist of the error is that I inadvertently connected the ImageCell of my view prototype back to the Collection View Item's representedObject outlet.

Here is a [sample project](http://cl.ly/TIvJ) that properly represents the problem. If you run it you'll see memory usage steadily growing and you won't see any dealloc messages in the console. Open MainMenu.xib and delete the bad reference from the Image Cell to the Collection View Item and when you re-run it'll behave properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason for my leak and posted it an update to my question but here it is again:

> The gist of the error is that I inadvertently connected the ImageCell
>   of my view prototype back to the Collection View Item's
>   representedObject outlet.

The newer sample project linked to above clearly demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a cache that the image is inserted into when using imageNamed.  And as the docs say on this- "the object may be quietly removed from the cache".  Note the "may".

You can see the same object coming back every time with this:

```
NSLog(@"%p",[CustomImage imageNamed:NSImageNameBluetoothTemplate]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Gus. I've updated the problem description with a better example.